# Subreddit, redditor object into JSON format

Tags: python, json, api, praw

I want to extract and store the entire subreddit object into JSON format.
I have come across ways to extract specific fields from the subreddit object and store them in JSON, however, I would like to store the entire object in JSON.
I have tried several ways.

First, I have done the following:

```
import requests
import pprint
import praw

ml_subreddit = reddit.subreddit('MachineLearning')
for submission1 in ml_subreddit.hot(limit=10):
    pprint.pprint(vars(submission1))
```

This gives me something that looks like a JSON and I am able to access some information about the post as we would access a JSON. However, I would also like to store and access the Redditor and comments objects in JSON format as well, which I am unable to do using this method.

I have tried another method:

```
import requests

for submission1 in ml_subreddit.hot(limit=10):
   url = submission1.permalink
   response = requests.get('http://reddit.com' + url + '.json') 
   json = response.content

json
```

This gives me a json saying
**
b'{"message": "Too Many Requests", "error": 429}'
**

How to I

1. Store the subreddit object in JSON format?
2. Store the Redditor and comments object into JSON format?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider some "time.sleep()" - if you hit a server with x requests under a second - it's obviously a robot beaviour and they can ban you or restrict your access. This error might be too many requests in specific time interval.

Comment: I'm quite certain praw should take care of preventing you from hitting the rate-limit, are you using it? But as @Leemosh said, your being timed out.

Comment: What can I do to prevent it?
I am using praw. I have got submission1, ml_subreddit and submission1.permalink using praw.
How can I use praw to limit the requests?

Also, how can I use time.sleep() to limit the requests?

Comment: I never used prew so I don't know anything more about it. But you can try to use sleeps - just put `time.sleep(1)` for example under the line `response = requests.get('http://reddit.com' + url + '.json') ` and don't forget to `import time`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still getting the same message.